# if statement vs function statement

Tags: javascript

**function statement** can be converted to an expression using operator like:

```
+function(){ //it is now function expression 
...
}();
```

But why the **if statement** cannot be converted to an expression?

```
+if(true){ //cause an error
....
}
```

Comment: You're not converting the *function* to an expression. You're evaluating the function (with the trailing `()`), and its result can be used in an expression.

Comment: I don't know anything about Javascript, but I doubt very much there's such thing as a function "statement". A function *definition* is itself an expression whose type is a function. A function *call* is an expression made up of a subexpression that is a function plus `()`. An `if` statement isn't an expression, it's a statement.

Comment: There just is no "if expression", while there are function expressions.

Comment: You might be looking for the ternary operator `true ? … : …`

Comment: just curious about that both are statement but function only can be used with such operator, thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not converting the *function* to an expression. You're evaluating the function (with the trailing `()`), and its result can be used in an expression. If you wanted to have something "if-like" inline in your code, use the ternary operator:

```
var a = b + (x > y ? c : d);
```

This is equivalent to the pseudocode you seem interested in:

```
// Of course the below isn't actually legal...
var a = b + if (x > y) {
    c;
} else {
    d;
}
```

Comment: is there any problem with the answers for downvoting and I'm accepting the wrong answer???

Comment: @C-linkNepal: I don't know why either answer was downvoted.  Downvotes on SO often make no sense.  :-)  (The sensible ones are usually accompanied by a comment explaining the reason for the downvote.)

Comment: That doesn't make sense but little confuses to me if I'm accepting wrong answer, no?

Comment: @C-linkNepal: Don't worry, you're not accepting a wrong answer.  You're accepting a helpful answer that some unknown person downvoted for no good reason.  (For good measure, I've upvoted it myself so that it's no longer in negative votes. :-) And if you feel it's helpful, you should upvote it yourself.)

Answer (score -1):

There is not really such a thing as a "function statement" in JavaScript.  A function definition is an *expression* returning a function, not a statement in the same sense as "`if` statement".

Using the unary plus on a function correctly returns `NaN`:

```
+function () { return "1"; }
NaN
```

(But if you **call** the function, as in your example, the return value will be used in your expression:

```
+function () { return "1"; }()
1
```

)

Comment: If you declare a function then it would be statement like `function func(){...}` is a statement...

Comment: @C-linkNepal: You're quite right that the phrase "function statement" gets used for that.  But it is in fact an *expression* returning a value, rather than a statement in the usual sense.  The phase "function statement" is rather misleading here.